# Mysql select crossreferencing 3 tables

Tags: mysql

The database is as follows:

```
Class_Memberships[id,user_id,class_id]
Class_Challenges[id,challenge_id,class_id]
Challenge_attempts[id,user_id,challenge_id,timestamp,solved]
```

I need to calculate the score which is how many attempts it took for a user to complete a challenge.

To do this globally (without taking into account the class) I run the following

```
SELECT user_id, time, count(*) as count, users.username
            FROM challenge_attempts LEFT JOIN users ON
            users.id = user_id WHERE status = 1
```

Which does the job and does not appear to have any bugs

I'm trying to limit the results for the users and challenges that belong to a specific class only.
Therefore my query becomes this

```
SELECT class_memberships.class_id, user_id, count(*) as count
FROM class_memberships,users,class_challenges
WHERE class_memberships.class_id = 4 AND
      users.id = user_id AND
  user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM challenge_attempts LEFT JOIN users ON
    users.id = user_id WHERE status = 1)
  AND class_challenges.challenge_id IN(
        SELECT challenge_id FROM class_challenges
    WHERE class_challenges.class_id = 4
    )
```

The

```
SELECT class_memberships.class_id, user_id, count(*) as count
FROM class_memberships,users,class_challenges
WHERE class_memberships.class_id = 4 AND
      users.id = class_memberships.user_id
```

part is supposed to get the the users in a class

The

```
SELECT user_id
    FROM challenge_attempts LEFT JOIN users ON
    users.id = user_id WHERE status = 1
```

is supposed to get their score

and finally the

```
SELECT challenge_id FROM class_challenges
    WHERE class_challenges.class_id = 4
```

Is supposed to limit the score to the challenges belonging to the class.
But when I try to run it sql outputs Column 'class_id' in field list is ambiguous

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what do you want with the COUNT(), but let'me know if it does not solve your problem.

```
SELECT t1.class_id, t1.user_id, count(t3.id) as count
FROM class_memberships t1
INNER JOIN users t2 ON (t2.id = t1.user_id)
INNER JOIN class_challenges t3 ON (t3.class_id = t1.class_id)
WHERE t1.class_id = 4 
    AND t1.user_id IN (
        SELECT t4.user_id
        FROM challenge_attempts t4
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = t4.user_id 
        WHERE status = 1
    )
GROUP BY t1.user_id, t1.class_id
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, count should tell us how many challenges that belong to the class the user has solved.